# String painting problem - properties of locus of continuous functions

Tags: geometry, continuity, problem-solving, word-problem, locus

The other day, I came up with a problem, but I do not know how to approach it with a solution.

**The problem:**

> Suppose, I have a string dipped in paint. Now I place that string onto a piece of paper arbitrarily and pull one end of the string in a fixed direction via a fixed point on the paper. (Note that the point and the direction is fixed for all such trials.) What are some properties of the geometry so traced out by the paint-smeared string, that remains invariant no matter which way I place the string?
>
> [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJ_6SKlC6q4&fbclid=IwAR1xckqll7Kb40bDgJ2oSHA_5naLfoTFfnDe9mIBBnIhN2gJRFuxeoc-eOI) is a YouTube video for a rough idea of string paintings.

Here are some concerns regarding the problem:

1. Is this a valid problem?
2. How can one approach such a problem?
3. Are there any generalisations that can be made without changing the properties of the plane resting underneath the string?

I am an undergraduate and have a background in linear algebra (Hoffman), analysis (Baby Rudin), abstract algebra (Herstein) and general topology (Munkres). Thanks in advance.

Comment: To give a meaningful answer one should model somehow the physical behaviour of the string, and friction plays a key role in that: I think that different density of paint, for instance, would heavily affect the motion of the string.

Comment: Hi, Aretino, sorry for the late (tending necro :P) reply, but I don't think this argument is true. A special case for my problem might just be the tractrix curve which does not rely on the friction, or heaviness of the string. I think further clarifications can be found in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184595/is-friction-necessary-for-a-tractrix-curve